# Error 438 when trying to call a sub method from a module class with parameters

Tags: excel, vba, oop, object

I get

> error 438 : Object does not support this property or method

when trying to run the following code. Could you help me with that please?

My macro code :

```
Sub test() 
   Dim upList As New ListRoot
   upList.msg 'this one works fine 

   Dim g As New Gradient
   upList.AppendRoot g 'line that raises the issue
End Sub
```

My module class code :

```
Public Sub AppendRoot(grad As Gradient)
    If IsEmpty(content.content) Then
       Set content.content = grad
    Else
       content.Append (grad)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub msg()
    MsgBox "HEY"
End Sub
```

I have already tried different calls of my method:

```
upList.AppendRoot(g) 
Call upList.AppendRoot(g)
```

and the one that is quoted above. None works.

Comment: What is `Gradient`? please provide a full [mcve].

Comment: Try stepping through the code using `F8`. It is likely that the error lies somewhere within the `AppendRoot` subroutine

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know the F8 thing, it was indeed an error 438 inside AppendRoot because of the parenthesis at the content.Append grad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that calling a sub/function without returning a value must be called without parenthesis:

```
content.Append grad
```

If the function returns some value then parenthesis *must* be added

```
ReturnValue = content.Append(grad)
```

But if you add parenthesis to a sub/function that **does not return** any value like you did

```
content.Append (grad)
```

… that forces the variable `grad` to be submitted `ByVal` while `ByRef` is the standard method to submit them. So by adding parenthesis here you change from `ByRef` to `ByVal` (you can also see that there is a space between the function/sub name and the parenthesis).

---

Example:

```
Sub TestFunction(Param1, Param2, Param3) 'all 3 parameters are ByRef by default in VBA (not in VB.NET!)

End Sub
```

Some examples to call this function:

```
'submit 3 parameters ByRef, don't return anything
TestFunction Param1, Param2, Param3 
TestFunction(Param1, Param2, Param3) 'throws error

'submit 3 parameters ByRef, return a Value
ReturnValue = TestFunction(Param1, Param2, Param3) 
ReturnValue = TestFunction Param1, Param2, Param3   'throws error 

'submit parameters 1 and 3 ByVal and 2 ByRef, don't return anything
TestFunction (Param1), Param2, (Param3) 

'submit parameters 1 and 3 ByVal and 2 ByRef, return a Value
ReturnValue = TestFunction((Param1), Param2, (Param3))
```

While with 3 parameters it will throw an error if you add parenthesis where they should not be, it will be more difficult with only one parameter:

```
TestFunction Param1   'correct
TestFunction (Param1) 'this threw an error with 3 parameters, but does not throw an error 
                      'with one parameter instead it changes behavior ByRef to ByVal
ReturnValue = TestFunction(Param1) 'correct
ReturnValue = TestFunction Param1  'throws error
```