# Save email to draft folder in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, cdo.message

I already have the codes to send emails but I don't want it to send I only want it to save in the drafts folder in Outlook.

I have tried adding `.Close` function and it doesn't work that way. Any idea?

```
    Dim iCfg As CDO.Configuration
    Dim iMsg As CDO.message
    Dim EmailAddr As String
    Dim wsEmail As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecast")
    Set wsEmail = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Recepient")

    Set iCfg = New CDO.Configuration
    With iCfg
        .Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = "XXX"
        .Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
        .Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
        .Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 200
        .Fields.Update
    End With

    Set iMsg = New CDO.message
    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iCfg
        .To = Worksheets("Recepient").Cells(5, 2).Value
        .cc = Worksheets("Recepient").Cells(5, 3).Value
        .From = "Automated Notification <NoReplyEmail@agit.com>"
        .Subject = "OPEN REQUEST " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = strBodyStandard
        .Close (olsave)
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iCfg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in CDO, I was browsing and couldn't find any result stating this. Maybe you can shift your approach to Outlook instead.

Comment: @Mikku i have been browsing too. I will look into shifting the approach to outlook

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
.Close olSave
```

[image]

**Instead of:**

```
.Close
```

`olSave` will save that mail in your Drafts Folder

---

**Your Code:**

```
    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iCfg
        .To = Worksheets("Recepient").Cells(5, 2).Value
        .cc = Worksheets("Recepient").Cells(5, 3).Value
        .From = "Automated Notification <NoReplyEmail@agit.com>"
        .Subject = "OPEN  REQUEST " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = strBodyStandard
        .Close olSave
        '.Send
    End With
```

Comment: i get a compile error: method or data member not found on `.Close`

Comment: I am using this in Excel

Comment: This is working in My system. You should paste your full code, must be some other issue.

Comment: @HarvintRaj ... Sorry Mate, I know about sending mails through Outlook. This will work if you are sending mails via Outlook. Don't know about CDO. Someone else will answer :)

Comment: Probably not an actual issue here but `.Close (olSave)` should be `.Close olSave`. In this case (if you use prenthesis on a method instead of function) the parenthesis would convert the paramater from `ByRef` to `ByVal` See [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579194/3219613). • Parenthesis should only be used at functions or methods (if the `Call` statement was used) or if you want to convert to `ByVal`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that doesn't seem to be the problem. i tried changing it.

Answer (score 0):

CDO doesn't provide any `Save` method. Moreover, it is a very old technology which is not used nowadays any longer. Instead, I'd suggest using the Outlook object model which provides the [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.save) method. You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)