# Range.Offset is turned into a Double

Tags: vba, offset

I have a strange behavior of a Range object: somehow it is turned into a Double.

here is my code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim RRange As Range
    Set RRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R4")
    Set RRange = RRange.Offset(0, -1)
    UpdateConditionalFormatting (RRange)
    UpdateConditionalFormatting (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R4"))

End Sub
```

So the first call of UpdateConditionalFormatting will crash the program (object required), the second will work. The sub requires the Range object

I don't know what is wrong here :(

```
Sub UpdateConditionalFormatting(ByVal rng As Range)

    With rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
     .SetFirstPriority
    .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
    .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = 8109667
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = 8711167
    .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = 7039480

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the brackets, use

```
UpdateConditionalFormatting RRange
```

instead of

```
UpdateConditionalFormatting (RRange)
```

Either that or use the `Call` syntax:

```
Call UpdateConditionalFormatting(RRange)
```

---

N.B: Also your 2nd call is providing a different `Range` because you didn't `Offset` it - this wouldn't cause the error you got, but I just thought I'd highlight it.

Comment: The reason it's happening I think, is because the brackets are shorthand to evaluate an expression if you're passing only ONE argument to a routine. Because `RRange` cannot be evaluated, it throws the error. The `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R4")` expression can be evaluated down to a Range object and therefore passes ok.

Comment: Actually the parenthesis convert from `ByRef` to `ByVal`. Checkout the full explanation about what the parenthesis do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579194/3219613)

Comment: worked like a charm! Indeed, I used to call my subs with `Call`, so I got it all mixed up. Thank you :)

Comment: It converts it to `ByVal` because it's trying to e`val`uate it?

Comment: @jamheadart well, technically exactly this, only the value gets submitted.