# Save slides 1 to 20 as new presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to save Slides 1 to Slide 20 (of 450 slides) as a new presentation.
New presentation name should be XYZ.pptx.

I tried:

```vb
Sub ExportSlides() 
    Dim myPresentation As Presentations 
    Set myPresentation = Presentations("PPTWITH450SLIDES.pptx").Slides.range(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)) 

    myPresentation.Export ("C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Droom Overview.pptx",FilterName:="pptx")  
End Sub
```

It is giving:

> Syntax Error

in the last line

```vb
myPresentation.Export ("C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Droom Overview.pptx",FilterName:="pptx")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually simpler to delete unwanted slides from a saved copy of your original presentation.  Like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSlides()

Dim x As Long

' Presentation not PresentationS
Dim myPresentation As Presentation

' If the presentation is already open:
' Set myPresentation = Presentations("exportable.pptx")

' otherwise
Set myPresentation = Presentations.Open("c:\temp\exportable.pptx")

myPresentation.SaveAs ("c:\temp\exported.pptx")
' The current presentation is now Exported.pptx

With myPresentation
    ' change 5 to the highest number slide you want to include + 1
    For x = .Slides.Count To 6 Step -1
        .Slides(x).Delete
    Next
End With

myPresentation.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Parenthesis in `myPresentation.SaveAs ("c:\temp\exported.pptx")` are not doing what you think. They turn your parameter from beeing submitted `ByRef` into `ByVal`. Either remove them or use `Call`. This is the same mistake why the OP got the Error, here it just works **by accident** because there is only one parameter. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579194/3219613

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you this was very very helpful @Steve Rindsberg but what if I want (for a 300 Slide PPT) to keep only slides 51-100 and delete slides 1-50 and 101-300

Comment: @RajatKapoor That's a very different question. In general terms, you could use the same strategy but use two loops:  From Slides.Count to UpperValue+1 Step -1, then From Slides(LowerValue-1) to 1 Step -1 where UpperValue and LowerValue are the top and bottom limits of the range  you want to preserve.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg Thank you for the suggestion. It did work!!

Answer (score 1):

You get the syntax error because you need to remove the parenthesis from

```
myPresentation.Export ("C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Droom Overview.pptx",FilterName:="pptx")
```

As the official documentation describes the [Presentation.Export method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.export) has no return value. Therfore it is not a function and has no parentesis for the parameters:

```
myPresentation.Export "C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Droom Overview.pptx", FilterName:="pptx"
```

Alternatively you can use the `Call` statement (with parenthesis):

```
Call myPresentation.Export("C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Droom Overview.pptx", FilterName:="pptx")
```

For further explanation also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579194/3219613

To do what you want it is easier to copy the entire presentation and delete the unnecessary slides as @SteveRindsberg suggested in his answer. The `Export` method is better used for exporting slides into images.